# In .NET Core 3.1, the RequestCookieCollection can no longer be used to create cookies in unit tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, cookies, asp.net-core-3.1

I have just upgraded from .NET Core 2.2 to 3.1. I have tests to confirm that extension methods I've added to `HttpContext.Request` are working. I was previously able to do things like:

```
    var context = new DefaultHttpContext();
    var c = new Dictionary<string, string> {{"test", "passed"}};
    context.Request.Cookies = new RequestCookieCollection(cookies);

    var result = context.Request.GetPrimedValue();
```

Is this impossible now? I tried using Moq for this, but there are far too many things blocking me from being able to set the Cookies property with anything usable, it seems. What is the resolution for this?

**note**: I understand that this was using an internal class which shouldn't have been internal, so I don't disagree with the internal namespace being hidden, but I'm not sure what my alternatives are.

Comment: Then mock `IRequestCookieCollection` Interface and setup the expected behavior

Comment: Please read the entire post. That would seemingly require an absurd amount of code to set up everything because I use this in the authorization process, and there seem to be a whole lot of checks just to make sure that the cookie collection you're creating can even be used to set the cookies property. When I use a mock for this and try to set the cookies property, there is a lot of validation which fails so the cookies property is never set.

Comment: @Dinerdo, did you happen to resolve this issue? I've been looking high and low for a solution as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am ignoring these tests for now. :(

Comment: I'm hitting the exact same restriction here. That thing is not mockable at all now. The time it requires to mock everything, is probably not well spent if everything around it tested... That's a real bummer.

Comment: I can create a RequestCookieCollection()  by adding "using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal;" statement. What's the question about?

Answer (score 19):

By manipulating some foundation classes, I am able to produce a mock cookie collection. However it is more like a workaround and might not work in future releases. You might want to give it a try and see how long it can go ...

With the helper function:

```
    private static IRequestCookieCollection MockRequestCookieCollection(string key, string value)
    {
            var requestFeature = new HttpRequestFeature();
            var featureCollection = new FeatureCollection();

            requestFeature.Headers = new HeaderDictionary();
            requestFeature.Headers.Add(HeaderNames.Cookie, new StringValues(key + "=" + value));

            featureCollection.Set<IHttpRequestFeature>(requestFeature);

            var cookiesFeature = new RequestCookiesFeature(featureCollection);

            return cookiesFeature.Cookies;
    }
```

Now your unit test code shall become

```
    var context = new DefaultHttpContext();

    context.Request.Cookies = MockRequestCookieCollection("test", "passed");
```

Answer (score 11):

I found that the simplest solution for my purposes was to leverage the fact that a `Dictionary<string, string>` is almost a complete implementation of `IRequestCookieCollection`. Just need to expose the `Keys` property as an `ICollection<string>`, and override the indexer, so that it returns null when asked for a non-existant key, instead of throwing:

```
public class RequestCookieCollection : Dictionary<string, string>, IRequestCookieCollection
{
    public new ICollection<string> Keys => base.Keys;
    public new string this[string key]
    {
        get
        {
            TryGetValue(key, out var value);
            return value;
        }
        set
        {
            base[key] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I found I needed to override the indexer so that, when asked for a non-existent cookie, it didn't throw, but instead returned null, like a cookie collection would.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77575838/how-to-override-dictionarys-get-item

Comment: @OutstandingBill That makes sense. Feel free to add that into the answer.

Answer (score 7):

Another way of mocking cookies by appending request headers.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
    // Arrange
    var controller = new Controller();
    var cookie = new StringValues(COOKIE_NAME + "=" + COOKIE_VALUE);
    controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext { HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext() };
    controller.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers.Add(HeaderNames.Cookie, cookie);

    // Act
    var result = Sut.Action();

    // Assert
    // TODO
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I can't add this as a comment, but if you create your own RequestCookieCollection class, based on the original one in the .net core codebase:

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/4ef204e13b88c0734e0e94a1cc4c0ef05f40849e/src/Http/Http/src/Internal/RequestCookieCollection.cs

Then you could use this new class to create your cookie collection in your unit tests project. I tried this approach and it works.

Answer (score 2):

@Victor6510's answer worked great for me until i needed to create a fake cookie that contained JSON. then i ran into this bug: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/29304 so i had to come up with additional way.

Using NSubstitute:

```
[TestClass]
public class ImpersonationMiddlewareTest
{
    private HttpContext _sHttpContext;
    private HttpRequest _sHttpRequest;
    private IRequestCookieCollection _sCookieCollection;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        _sHttpContext = Substitute.For<HttpContext>();
        _sHttpRequest = Substitute.For<HttpRequest>();
        _sCookieCollection = Substitute.For<IRequestCookieCollection>();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task Invoke_GoodCookie_CreatesImpersonationIdentity()
    {
        //arrange
        var cookieList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string,string>("cookiename", "cookievalue")
        };
        _sCookieCollection.GetEnumerator().Returns(e => cookieList.GetEnumerator());
        _sCookieCollection.ContainsKey("cookiename").Returns(true);

        _sHttpRequest.Cookies.Returns(_sCookieCollection);

        _sHttpContext.Request.Returns(_sHttpRequest);

        //act
        myMiddleware.InvokeAsync(_sHttpContext);

        //assert
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A very simple solution is to use [ImpromptuInterface](https://github.com/ekonbenefits/impromptu-interface), a duck casting framework.

```
// using ImpromptuInterface;

var context = new DefaultHttpContext();
var c = new Dictionary<string, string> {{"test", "passed"}};
context.Request.Cookies = c.ActLike<IRequestCookieCollection>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the question author resisted the idea of mocking `IRequestCookieCollection`, but ReSharper makes it easy to build a mock which can be adapted as needed. Here's what I did.

1. Create a mock class of IRequestCookieCollection.

   ```
   private class MockRequestCookieCollection : IRequestCookieCollection
   {

   }
   ```
2. Allow ReSharper to implement the missing members.

   ```
   private class MockRequestCookieCollection : IRequestCookieCollection
   {
       public string? this[string key] => throw new NotImplementedException();

       public int Count => throw new NotImplementedException();

       public ICollection<string> Keys => throw new NotImplementedException();

       public bool ContainsKey(string key)
       {
           throw new NotImplementedException();
       }

       public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, string>> GetEnumerator()
       {
           throw new NotImplementedException();
       }

       public bool TryGetValue(string key, out string? value)
       {
           throw new NotImplementedException();
       }

       IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
       {
           throw new NotImplementedException();
       }
   }
   ```
3. Build out the members you need. For my purposes, I needed to add a field and constructor and complete the indexer.

   ```
    private readonly IDictionary<string, string> _cookies;

    public MockRequestCookieCollection(IDictionary<string, string> cookies)
    {
        _cookies = cookies;
    }

    public string? this[string key]
    {
       get
       {
           try
           {
               return _cookies[key];
           }
           catch
           {
               return null;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. Use the mock in tests.

   ```
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "foo", "1" },
        { "bar", "2" }
    };
    var cookies = new MockRequestCookieCollection(dictionary);
   ```

Disclaimer: I used Visual Studio 2022 and .NET 6, but the concepts should work in .NET Core 3.1.

Comment: Just a note: using try-catch block is a performance killer when there is another way to achieve the same functionality (e.g. ````TryGetValue````). I see this is a mock implementation but somebody once said me that every code coming out of my hands should have the best quality regardless whether it is a production or test :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
     /// helper class for cookies
     public class FakeCookieCollection : Dictionary<string, string>,IRequestCookieCollection
     {
            public new ICollection<string> Keys => ((Dictionary<string, string>) this).Keys;
     }
    
    
     // in your unit test class
     public class MyControllerTest {
        FakeCookieCollection FakeCookieCollection { get; set; }
        HttpContext FakeHttpContext { get; set; }

        public MyControllerTest() {
           // mock services
           _controller = new MyController(...);
    
           FakeCookieCollection = new FakeCookieCollection();
           FakeHttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
           FakeHttpContext.Request.Cookies = FakeCookieCollection;
           FakeCookieCollection.Add("blabla","value");  // you can also add cookies directly in test methods
           _controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext { HttpContext = FakeHttpContext };
       }
   }
```