# Handle RequestCookieCollection class in .net6

Tags: .net-6.0

RequestCookieCollection class is not supported in .net 6. I want to make below code compatible in .net6 as i have migrated my application from .netcore2.1 to .net6

```
    Dictionary<string, string> cookies = new Dictionary<string, string>(); 
foreach (var existingCookie in context.Request.Cookies)                 
      cookies.Add(existingCookie.Key, existingCookie.Value); 
var collection = new RequestCookieCollection(cookies); 
context.Request.Cookies = collection;
```

Comment: I want to make is compatible above code with .net6

Comment: Good solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70086346/392184